# Filter TreeView bound to an ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, treeview, observablecollection

I am new to WPF/Observable Collection. 
We are using Populating TreeView with the list which is Observable Collection.

I am trying to filter my Tree wherein even if the Root Node/Parent  fails the criteria and the child node satisfies, I can't filter the Parent Node.

Since the child node satisfied the criteria, it should show with the whole Tree Path of the child.

```
Root
  Animal
     Dog
     Cat
  Fish
     Fresh Water
     Salt Water
```

When you search for "water",   It should display Root-- Fish-Fresh Water-Salt Water.

Answer (score -1):

So far the best out-of-the-box filtering and sorting that I have found is the CollectionView and CollectionViewSource duo.

I have a post which goes into detail of how to use them here:
[WPF ListBoxItem Visibility and ScrollBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6655968/wpf-listboxitem-visibility-and-scrollbar/6656278#6656278)

Essentially what you are doing is hosting the collection inside the CollectionViewSource, and adding Filter and Sort definitions to a Viewobject when tells the ItemsControl (ListBox, ListView, TreeView) in which items to display and the order to display them.  In this way you are not changing your collection, or manipulating individual items across several collections.

## Example

All of my business object classes are hosted in ViewModels.  The ViewModels each have a property named MyRecord of the type of class for that ViewModel (this way later on I can call that method regardless of which ViewModelType I am working on, yay Late Binding!)

Anyhow as I recall, my filter method looked something like this:

```
    private bool FilterByString(string filterString)
    {
        foreach (CustomerViewModel custVM in cvs.Source)
        {
            FilterChild(filterString, custVM);
            if (custVM.MatchesFilter(filterString))
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
    }

    private bool FilterChild(string filterString, Object parent)
    {
        bool match = false;
        if (parent.MyChildren != null && parent.MyChildren.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Object Child in parent.MyChildren)
            {
                //If any of the children return true, then this method returns true.
                //if all children return false, this method returns false.
                bool innerMatch = Child.MatchesFilter(filterString);
                match = (match == false ? innerMatch : match);
                Child.MatchesFilter(filterString);
                FilterChild(filterString, Child);
            }

        }
        bool outerMatch = parent.MatchesFilter;
        if (outerMatch || match)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now I remember.  I was not actually filtering the children, I was just setting them to be collapsed.  I had the expanded property on each item set to a property on the ViewModel and that property was set when the MatchesFilter method was called.  Only the top level items were filtered (and only if every item under them did not match the filter.

This is likely not the functionality that you were looking for, but at the moment, it is what I have.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't seem to work for me :( Not sure whether it would work for Hierarchical data. It applies the filter at the Root level but not doing the filter at the Child level nodes.  I may be doing something wrong. Just wanted to confirm with you if you had tested this with Tree View - Hierarchical data as I showed in my Example.

Comment: In the above example, Search works only on "Animal" and "Fish" and it doesn't apply to the child elements. If I type "d", its not returning anything since "d" is not in "Animal" or "Fish". I would have wanted Animal--> Dog to show since Dog has "d". Please let me know how do I apply the filter at all levels of the Tree.

Comment: In your filter logic method, you will need some method for checking child objects to see if they match the filter.  I can't find the example that I was hoping to post for you.  In it, I had an instance method on each class in the hierarchy that took a string and returned bool for matches filter.  Then in my filter logic I just had a block that walked all the way down the tree getting items back and bubbling the value back to the top level.  (Come to think of it, I also had to have a property on the classViewModels for expanded which I set = to matches filter...)

Comment: Thanks for your example. 
I am trying to achieve the filtering using the Visibility property of the TreeViewItem.
I am Binding this to a property of my Entity and setting the Visibility based on the filtered text. 
The behaviour I am seeing with this is that, after Filtering it is showing the Nodes that did not match the criteria as Blank Nodes ie no name next to the Node.

Comment: It looks like someone else got it working using several CollectionViews.  I have not tried this, but it looks like it might be a step in the right direction for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321217/filtering-a-hierarchical-object-displayed-with-nested-xaml-data-templates

Comment: not sure I need multiple CollectionViews, since I am dealing with just one ObservableCollection of Hierarchical Items. To filter the Child Objects under the Root Folder, I have created Predicate Filter Object at the Entity Level and setting its filter to the same Filter as the Root Objects. Its kind of working, but I am not able to clear the Filter for the child elements. When I clear the Filter, it clears only the Root folders. Child elements under it are still filtered.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395960/how-to-clear-filter-in-collectionviewsource-for-all-child-objects

Comment: The reason I added Predicate Filter Object for each Entity is that, it should filter out the child elements that doesn't meet the Filter criteria. Without setting the filter at Entity level, I am not able to filter out the leaf nodes. As in the above Example, when I type "d", Cat should be left out. This doesn't happen if I don't set the filter at the Each entity level.

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I am at a loss on that bit.